# Can't install bower in Linux

Tags: linux, bower, linux-mint, bower-install

I try to install bower.

I use Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela

I have node v0.10.25 and npm 1.3.10

I try to run in the terminal:

```
 sudo npm install -g bower
```

and get:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm ERR! Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1370:32)
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:982:10)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:469:13)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.Readable.read 
(_stream_readable.js:320:10)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:366:25)
npm ERR!     at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:223:10)
npm ERR!     at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:213:5)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.Writable.write 
(_stream_writable.js:180:11)
npm ERR!     at write (_stream_readable.js:583:24)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-109-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" 
"bower"
npm ERR! cwd /
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, node v0.10.25 is REALLY old (23.01.2014). Also npm 1.3.10 ... please update node/npm to a more recent version (node: 8 or 10, npm: 5.6):

https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

Second: As the error message tells, it is a certificate error. Reasons for that migth be the outdated versions ...

Comment: yes. you are right. I updated all as here https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa